# why so many "\" s there in this code...what is the usage of it..?

Tags: java, servlets

I am a beginner to servlets..and I got a question seeing this code written inside a servlet.I'll be thankful if someone explain me the usage of soo many"\"s here

```
"<form method=\"post\" action =\"" + request.getContextPath( ) +
        "/firstservlet\" >");

out.println("<table border=\"0\"><tr><td valign=\"top\">");
out.println("Your first name: </td>  <td valign=\"top\">");
out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" size=\"20\">");
out.println("</td></tr><tr><td valign=\"top\">");
out.println("Your last name: </td>  <td valign=\"top\">");
out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"lastname\" size=\"20\">");
out.println("</td></tr><tr><td valign=\"top\">");
out.println("Your email: </td>  <td valign=\"top\">");
out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" size=\"20\">");
out.println("</td></tr><tr><td valign=\"top\">");

out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit Info\"></td></tr>");
out.println("</table></form>");
out.println("</body></html>");
```

Comment: to escape special characters.

Comment: If I were you. I would make use of a properties file instead of having nasty escaped strings.

Comment: This looks very bad coading, Please try to use JSP for view

Comment: Don't read outdated books/tutorials. HTML doesn't belong in servlets. HTML belongs in JSP. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 17):

You must escape the quotes `"` inside Strings by writing `\"`. If you don't do this, the Strings will end too early.

**Edit:** Example:

```
String thisWillNotCompile =  "This String terminates right now" and not later";
```

Trying to compile this will give you a syntax error.

```
String thisWillCompile = "This String doesn't terminate right now\" but now";
```

This works.

**Edit 2:** For more details read up on [Escape Sequences in the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: can u explain that by a small example..??

Comment: Try taking the backslashes out of the example you provided and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

It's to indicate that the character `"` is not a special character that marks the end of the string, but it's part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`\` known as escape character in programming languages. You use this to escape some special characters. For example if you want to print a string called

```
Hello " World
```

If you specify

```
system.out.println("Hello " World"); // Sorry Error :(
```

This will give an error because `"` is a special character. So you need to escape this by putting

```
system.out.println("Hello \" World"); // It works :)
```