# Handle file save with two slashes separation convert

Tags: java, file, escaping

When I save file from pop up the path is like this format

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\ed\file001.xml
```

But to save it I need to use:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\ed\\file001.xml"))).
```

I.E. two slash separate between the folder.

Is there a standard way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslashes need to be escaped in String **literals**, because they're a special character. But the String literal `"a\\b"` is in fact a String containing a, one backslash, and b. If you print it, it will display `a\b`. Just like the String literal `"a\nb"` is a String containing a, one newline character, and b.

You don't have anything to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since the backslash `\` *escapes* the following character, you must escape it in a String.

See [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109879/why-so-many-s-there-in-this-code-what-is-the-usage-of-it/9109897#9109897) of mine on a similar question where the character to be escaped is `"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `/` instead of `\\`. Or use use `File.separatorChar` this is the system-dependent default name-separator character.

```
new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/ed/file001.xml"))).
```