# Why does "//" instead of "\\" for Spyder on Ubuntu compared to Spyder on Windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, ubuntu, spyder

I wrote a python script, where I need to read and write a file. I first wrote it on Windows, and the when I tried to execute the same code on Ubuntu(Linux), using the same Python Shell (Spyder), I got this message error "No such file or directory:"data.csv". I had many attempts to fix this trouble, at the end, I found out that I need to change all '\' by '//' inside my code. So, everything is working well right now, but WHY!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why so many "\" s there in this code...what is the usage of it..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109879/why-so-many-s-there-in-this-code-what-is-the-usage-of-it)

Comment: @Mack That's a completely different use for backslash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Windows uses backslashes as directory separators, and POSIX systems (including Linux) use *forward* slashes. See the [`os.sep` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep):

> The character used by the operating system to separate pathname components. This is `'/'` for POSIX and `'\\'` for Windows.

Always use the `os.path` module to construct paths; it'll take care of platform differences.

Comment: `pathlib` is another option for handling paths in cross-platform code -- especially in 3.6+ in which there's better support for it in the standard library.